# Oracle Apex 4.2 Interactive Report Column Value Truncation

Tags: oracle, report, oracle-apex, interactive, truncation

I'm working with an interactive report in Oracle Apex 4.2 and am noticing the value I've inputted into a particular entry has been truncated to 500 characters within my interactive report view.

Within the entry itself I am able to see all the characters that were inputted (in my example 747 characters).

I'm looking for some help on how I can correct this issue. I've experimented with both column width, column height, CSS formats, etc and can't seem to fix it.

Unfortunately I can't post images as I don't have the reputation points yet so here are links to the images.....

(**Truncated view in interactive report**)
[image]

(**Non-truncated original submission**)
[image]

Would really appreciate any help I can get on this!

Thanks!

Comment: there may be a built-in restriction somewhere, you could inspect element to see if any CSS restrictions. Jorge describes something you may be interested here http://rimblas.com/blog/2014/02/long-text-strategies/

Comment: Have you checked that the query itself doesn't truncate the value?

Answer (score 0):

I tried to solve this issue,I found that there is no built-in  restriction in Oracle apex.It might be restriction that has been given at element level in form such as **maximum width : 500** :[image]

If you insert text more that maximum width then automatically truncate to avoid errors.To ensure this please enter text by query.

Hope this will help you..